# Which module implements CreateWindowW on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dllimport

I just came across issue in my application where i need to get static address of [`CreateWindowW`](http://search.microsoft.com/search/results.aspx?qu=CreateWindow) function. Just like this:

```
&ShowWindow;
```

However, when doing the same trick with `CreateWindowW`, i get *compiler error* `Identifier "CreateWindowW" is undefined` (it's a macro). I actually cannot find where this function is defined (which DLL) and even [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CreateWindow.html) does not mention this.

On some website there is a mention it is `user32.dll`, but `GetProcAddress` for my function inside it returns null pointer. I am lost, which module on Windows is linked for this function?

If i try to connect debugger and trace call to this function, Visual Studio makes "Step over" it so i cannot understand where the call goes to..

My build is UNICODE. **WinUser.h text i can see**:

```
#define CreateWindowA(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
CreateWindowExA(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
#define CreateWindowW(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
CreateWindowExW(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateWindow  CreateWindowW
#else
#define CreateWindow  CreateWindowA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Comment: `#define CreateWindowW(...) CreateWindowExW(...)` didn't give it away?

Comment: Now it is clear, but not when you read MSDN page of function "CreateWindow" and you sure it is not macro. Macro may not have typed arguments, while MSDN page defines this as function with arguments which do have types. While there is no mentioning it is "macro" or "wrapper" (as @VioletGiraffe called this function on their own decision), MSDN says (at the end of article) it is "implemented as call to CreateWindowEx". This does not tell me anything informative and clearly documentation problem. The page is titled as "CreateWindow function" on MSDN.

Comment: From [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx): *"CreateWindow is implemented as a call to the CreateWindowEx function, **as shown below**."* It is explicitly spelled out that it is a macro (in the accompanying code). Clearly a problem of not reading the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the `CreateWindow` [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx) and scroll down, you will see that it is implemented as a wrapper around `CreateWindowEx`. And if you open the [CreateWindowEx doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) and scroll down, you'll see this:

[image]

So it's implemented in `User32.dll`.

Answer (score 6):

`CreateWindowExW` is exported by `user32.dll`. You can just check the documentation. Or you can check the exports via e.g. Microsoft's `dumpbin` tool.

```
> dumpbin /exports c:\windows\system32\user32.dll | find /i "CreateWindow"

       1618   6D 0000A230 CreateWindowExA
       1619   6E 000107B8 CreateWindowExW
       1620   6F 00041530 CreateWindowStationA
       1621   70 000014D0 CreateWindowStationW
```

`CreateWindowW` is a thin wrapper implemented as a macro, according to [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **”** `CreateWindow` is implemented as a call to the `CreateWindowEx` function, as shown below.
>
> ```
> #define CreateWindowA(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
> CreateWindowExA(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
>
> #define CreateWindowW(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
> CreateWindowExW(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)
>
> #ifdef UNICODE
> #define CreateWindow  CreateWindowW
> #else
> #define CreateWindow  CreateWindowA
> #endif
> ```

You can also check that by e.g. “Go to definition” in Visual Studio.